# List all file in directory using python in widows

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to use listdir to list all files in a directory in windows.
I need to list all files in the location  `C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract\`, it gives an error 
`"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"`

```
import os
arr = os.listdir('C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract')
print(arr)
```

Comment: 2 potential problems: (1) incorrect indentation - Python uses indentation to define code blocks (2) escape sequences in path - use a raw string instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the string.

Replace:

```
'C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract'
```

**With (escape the backslashes),**

```
'C:\\Users\\jibin\\Desktop\\CDR\\CDR_Extract'
```

**Or, use forward slashes instead of backlashes,**

```
'C:/Users/jibin/Desktop/CDR/CDR_Extract'
```

**Or, you can put `r` in front of string to convert normal string to raw string,**

```
r'C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use glob module, see the example bellow (its generic approach for listing and doing some thing with files you want to locate)

```
import glob
import os

def rmf_handler(arg,cdir,names):
    # for example we want to remove *.pyc files from current directory
    for path in glob.glob(cdir+'\*.pyc'):
        print 'remove {ppath}'.format(ppath=path)
        os.remove(path)

def rmm(root):
    os.path.walk(root,rmf_handler,None)

# call it:
rmm(root_dir)
```